# Emojis sent from a Samsung device appear as "two question marks" on the recipient's device

Tags: samsung, emoticons

I recently switched from my iPhone 7 to a Samsung Galaxy S10. However, for some reason when I send emojis, the recipient receives two question marks.

I've exchanged my phone, but the problem remains.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If the recipient doesn't use a device that supports the specific emoji, this happens.

Example:

- All the emoji on Android Oreo (8.0) aren't on Android Lollipop (5.0)
- Not every emoji on iOS is supported on Android or vice versa

If you are sure that their device supports the emoji, I don't know then.